# Is there a way to add context to Django reverse function?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Is it possible to pass context through the reverse function in Django in some way like `reverse('foo', context={'bar':'baz'})`? Or is there a better workaround?

Comment: No, `reverse` only produces a string: a path. When the browser then visits that path, it will invoke the view named `'foo'`.

Comment: What is `context`? Since you mentioned Django, is this the context that you pass to a template when you render it? Why do you want to pass it to `reverse()`? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes I think the `context` is of template that is passed  in `render()` and not `kwargs` and yes you thought it right it is a XY problem.

Comment: You were right - ```reverse``` was not the right solution... I ended up using ```render()``` instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already described by Sir [WillemVanOnsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) in the above comment.

You can't provide `context` in reverse as it only produces a string: a path, eventually it goes to view.

[`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) can only take `args` and `kwargs`, see [Reversing namespaced URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse generates an URL. The URL can parse or supply extra context. In urls.py,

```
path( 'action/<str:context>/', MyView.as_view(), name='foo' )
```

then

```
reverse('app:foo', kwargs={'context':'bar:baz+quux:help'} )
```

will generate the URL ending

```
.../appname/action/bar:baz+quux:help
```

and your view will parse context:

```
context = self.kwargs.get( context, '')
context_dir = {}
for kv in context.split('+'):
   keyval = kv.split(':')
   context_dir[ keyval[0].strip() ] = keyval[1].strip()
```

or something like this, ending with context_dir as `{'bar':'baz', 'quux':'help'}`

Alternatively you can append a querystring to the URL returned by reverse and retrieve that in the view you redirect to via request.GET

```
url = reverse('foo') + '?bar=baz&quux=help'
```

redirect, and then in that view `request.GET.get('bar')` will return `"baz"` etc.

Finally you can stuff an almost arbitrarily complex context into the user's session (which gets stored either as a cookie in his browser, or an object in your database). This is the most general but also the most complex. See the doc for [using Django sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/)

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `view = resolve(url)` and then build a request object to pass to `view`. However, this seems like something we shouldn't do. I suspect this is an XY problem with a much simpler solution than what the OP is asking about.